# Standard approach to handle dependencies in a Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies, visual-studio-2019

This will be more of a theoretical question. I am working on a bigger project, using Visual Studio 2019 as IDE. I use `Visual C++`, `Qt`, `OpenCV`, `spdlog` and potentially other dependencies. I want to make this project super easy to download and configure, possibly to dowload every dependency automatically when one wants to try my application out. I was thinking of using Docker, but I have no experience with it, and it seems like it is used for web development mainly.

What is the standard approach? Can you point me in a direction? Any suggestions are welcome.

Up until now I dowloaded and configured everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems like there is no such approach. I ended up using CMake, so in `CMakeLists.txt` the dependencies can be seen easily. And for packages I used `vcpkg` as a package manager - although it did not work with Qt6 for some reason. Still, any other answers are welcome.